# What is the right way to pass a pointer to my function?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I've a function prototype:

```
int array_length(char *(ptr)[1024]){
...
}
```

I want to call this function into another function. I have:

```
char array_slave[128][1024];
char (*ptr)[1024] = array_slave;
array_length(&ptr);
```

As the compiler says, this is wrong. But why? Can you explain me "theorically" how to do in this situation? What is the reasoning to do?

Comment: `int array_length(char *(ptr)[1024]){` --> `int array_length(char (*ptr)[1024]){`, otherwise the function signature is _**array of pointers to `char`**_ and you want a _**pointer to array of 1024 `char`s**_, also, you need to pass `array_length(ptr);` without the ampersand.

Comment: Unless you have specialized reasons why you need the function to use an array pointer, then consider `int array_length (char ptr[][1024])` instead. And call it as `array_length(array_slave)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `ptr` is already `char(*)[1024]`. Thus the type of `&ptr` is a pointer to pointer to an array `char(**)[1024]`. It differs from what the function expects thus a warning is raised. Just skip `&`:

```
array_length(ptr);
```

Alternatively you can pass `array_slave` directly because an array of `char[1024]` decays to a pointer to its first element producing pointer of `char(*)[1024]` type.

```
array_length(array_slave);
```